# Should I use bit manipulation on float point numbers

Tags: c++, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I'm writing an algorithm, to round a floating number. The input will be a 64bit IEEE754 double type number, very close to X.5, where X is a integer less than 32. The first solution came into my mind is to use a bit mask, to mask off those least significant bits as they represent very small fractions of 2^-n.(Given the exponent is not large).

But the problem is should I do that? Is there any other ways to accomplish the same thing? I feel using bit operation on float point is very controversy. Thanks!

The langugage I'm using is C++ by the way.

Edit:
Thanks guys, for your comments. I appreciate! Let's say I have a float number, can be 1.4999999... or 21.50000012.... I want to round it to 1.5 or 21.5. My goal is to round any number to its nearest to X.5 form, since it can be stored in a IEEE754 float point number.

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is. You're just listing your possible solutions for some unknown goal. Did you want us to tell you how to bitwise round a floating-point number?

Comment: Exactly what type of rounding are you hoping to do?

Comment: Why don't you use standard library functions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That will be the best. But I don't know if there is any fit my purpose. I just updated my question. Can you help to have a look? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by round to X.5, should 2.1 be rounded to 2.0 or 2.5?

Comment: @aka.nice 2.0, to the nearest integral or half intergral number.

Comment: @CodingSiberian then +1 to answers of David after modification of Pascal (for portability) and Pascal for the very nice hack (and also for the fact that it will work with alternative rounding modes - ceil floor trunc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your compiler guarantees that you are using IEEE 754 floating-point, I would recommend that you round according to the method delineated in [this blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/04/nearbyintf3): add, and then immediately subtract a large constant so as to send the value in the binade of floating-point numbers where the ULP is 0.5. You won't find any faster method, and it does not involve any bit manipulation.

The appropriate constant to round a number between 0 and 32 to the nearest halt-unit for IEEE 754 double-precision is `2251799813685248.0`.

Summary: use `x = x + 2251799813685248.0 - 2251799813685248.0;`.

Comment: What if your compiler is stupid and turns that into `x = x`? (like ICC - you can pass `-mp` to make it work but that makes it quite inefficient)

Comment: @harold `volatile double tmp = x + 2251799813685248.0; x = tmp - 2251799813685248.0;` ought to discourage any optimization, but I do not have ICC and I cannot try this (and I would always pass `-mc` if I were using it, because I like my floating-point predictable).

Comment: `volatile` did the trick (with some redundant moves), `-mp` really isn't pretty, that makes it use x87 instructions and store/reload temporary values. edit: actually, even just using a non-volatile `tmp` does the trick. Weirdness.

Comment: @harold I misunderstood what `-mc` was. I meant: “if I was using ICC, I would use the options that make it generate SSE2 floating-point instructions and follow exactly the source code's semantics for floating-point computations (type and order of operations).” I am sure that ICC must have some options to give it this behavior.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that it has that option (unlike most compilers). At least, I don't know of it, and I couldn't find it after searching for about 5 minutes.

Comment: @PascalCuoq It's amazing! Thanks! But the use of volatile seems can be a hit on the performance. And is there any spec/paper can prove your original equaltion won't be optimized? I like this solution.

Comment: @CodingSiberian There is only one temporary variable with `volatile` qualifier in my answer, to force the compiler to do the addition and subtraction. It is faster without the volatile only inasmuch as it does not do the addition and subtraction, and then, it does not round. The is the only effect of this qualifier. It does not make anything slow, it only makes it work. The C++ standard already specifies that `x + C - C` is `(x + C) - C`. A compiler that does not translate it as such is a non-conforming compiler.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, Thanks for the explanation! Do you have the reference of which part of C++ standard specified that?

Comment: @CodingSiberian C++2003 5.7:1 “The additive operators + and - group left-to-right”. The grammar is the same clause re-express the same thing more formally.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I just find out on C++ 11 standard, floating point's representation is implementation specific...

Answer (score 5):

You can use any of the functions `round()`, `floor()`, `ceil()`, `rint()`, `nearbyint()`, and `trunc()`. All do rounding in different modes, and all are standard C99. The only thing you need to do is to link against the standard math library by specifying `-lm` as a compiler flag.

As to trying to achieve rounding by bit manipulations, I would stay away from that: a) it will be much slower than using the functions above (they generally use hardware facilities where possible), b) it is reinventing the wheel with a lot of potential for bugs, and c) the newer C standards don't like you doing bit manipulations on floating point types: they use the so called strict aliasing rules that disallow you to just cast a `double*` to an `uint64_t*`. You would either need to do your bit manipulation by casting to a `unsigned char*` and manipulating the IEEE number byte by byte, or you would have to use `memcpy()` to copy the bit representation from a `double` variable into an `uint64_t` and back again. A lot of hassle for something already available in the form of standardized functions and hardware support.

Comment: Thanks, and agreed. I too feel the standard don't like bit manipulations on float point numbers. That's why I'm seeking for alternatives to bit mask. I've checked the cmath functions with the help from your post. But seems none of them solve my question directly. Do you know any other solutions? I appreciate it!

Comment: @CodingSiberian What do you mean by "seems none of them solve my question directly"? What features are you missing? In what respect do these functions do something other than what you want to do?

Comment: If you have a `double d` than `floor(d) + 0.5` gives you your desired result. It truncates to an integer value (1.9 goes to 1, 1.05 goes to 1), and adds 0.5. Since your numbers should be close to an integer plus 0.5, then finding the integer part than adding 0.5 to restrict it to the desired value will give you the result you want.

Answer (score 4):

You want to round `x` to the nearest value of the form `d.5`. For a generan number you write:

```
round(x+0.5)-0.5
```

For a number close to `d.5`, less than 0.25 away, you can use Pascal's offering:

```
round(2*x)*0.5
```

Comment: I'll bet you that this gets some answers wrong (but then again, the question makes it clear that the numbers considered are close to X.5, so it does not matter). `round(2*x)*0.5` would be clearly correct for all possible floating-point numbers between 0 and 32.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks! That is pretty straight forward. My thought on using bit manipulation is for speed. And I post the mask based solution to see if there is any other solution can be fast, and roburst. Do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: Why do you think this will be slow? What are your performance constraints? Is this calculation your program's bottleneck?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I haven't run profiler yet. But it will be called many times in short time period.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Another question about Pascal's solution is: Is that portable? Considering the different FPU on the PC/Server market. Can that code be run on different floating pointer execution architect?

Comment: @CodingSiberian It's more portable than your bit twiddling!  ;-)

Comment: @CodingSiberian If you are not using a base-16 IBM system from the seventies or a decimal IBM System z9 or z10, you should be fine. Even if you were, only a few borderline case could be computed differently. You would not notice the difference because you said to assume that the values to round are very close to X.5.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, Thanks Pascal, David. I really appreciate your examples and explanation. I'm going to close the question. Please enlight me more for anything I'm missing!

Comment: It's not only better, it's very different. round(x+0.5)-0.5 would round 2.1 to 2.5, round(2*x)*0.5 will round 2.1 to 2.0 as requested.

Comment: @aka.nice It's the other way around. The desied output is of the form `d.5` and so `2.0` is no good.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just asked for clarification, it's 2.0. Otherwise, note that round(x-0.5)+0.5 would work better w.r.t. predecessor of 0.5 (and in the full range 0->32)

Comment: @aka The question itself says "My goal is to round any
number to its nearest to X.5 form" so it's somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a bit trick and are guaranteed to have doubles in the ranges you describe, then you could do something like this (inline as you see fit):

```
void RoundNearestHalf(double &d) {
    unsigned const          maskshift  = ((*(unsigned __int64*)&d >> 52) - 1023);
    unsigned __int64 const  setmask    =  0x0008000000000000 >> maskshift;
    unsigned __int64 const  clearmask  = ~0x0007FFFFFFFFFFFF >> maskshift;
    *(unsigned __int64*)&d            |= setmask;
    *(unsigned __int64*)&d            &= clearmask;
}
```

`maskshift` is the unbiased exponent. For the input range, we know this will be non-negative and no more than 4 (the trick will work for higher values too, but no more than 51). We use this value to make a `setmask` which sets the 2^-1 (one-half) place in the mantissa, and `clearmask` which clears all bits in the mantissa of lower value than 2^-1. The result is `d` rounded to the nearest half.

Note that it would be worth profiling this against other implementations, perhaps using the standard library to determine whether or not its actually faster.

Comment: I appreciate your example and your help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak about C++ for sure, but in C99 the use of IEEE 754 standard for floating point will be purely normative (not required). In C99 if the `__STDC_IEC_559__` macro is set then it declares that IEC 559 (which is more or less IEEE 754) is used for floating point.

I think it should be pointed out that there are functions to handle many types of rounding for you.